Javascript changes to options of select do not apply
I am programming a Rails app with a view with inline JavaScript also using jquery. When clicking the button with Id="ReloadPlaceholders" the script is executed which is fine, wanted and works.
The script itself doesnt work. It is supposed to:

load data from the server [WORKS]
select a drop down [WORKS]
empty the drop down with [DOESN'T WORK - The drop down options remain unchanged (but the drop down flickers shortly...dunno why)
Populate the drop down with the new options. To test this I added an Option [DOESN'T WORK] (later the options from the var will be loaded)

My code in the view:
document.getElementById("ReloadPlaceholders").addEventListener("click",
  function() {
    const xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlHttp.open("GET", "/home/companies/<%= current_company.id %>/disbursements/placeholders", true); // false for synchronous request
    xmlHttp.onload = (e) => {
      var options = xmlHttp.responseText;
      let newOption = new Option('Option Text', 'Option Value');
      const select = document.querySelector('#disbursement_disbursement_positions_attributes_0_placeholder_id');
      select.empty();
      select.add(newOption, undefined);
    };
    xmlHttp.onerror = (e) => {
      console.error(xmlHttp.statusText);
    };
  }
);

I tried for multiple hours also using plain vanilla JS but it doesnt work.

What select? Could you add the HTML? As far as I know with a base HTML <select> element you would have to append and remove <option> nodes. For example, select.empty() is not listed on the MDN docs. You could simulate that with select.innerHTML = ''. You can also ommit the undefined from your .add() call to ensure that that isn't expecting a null instead or something.

Please see [mcve].   Narrow down to the issue you're asking (changing select options) and remove anything else (the event listener, the ajax request) and add enough HTML to reproduce the issue in the question.

Copying (the relevant parts of) your code to a jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/yxd9nrsv/  gives error select.empty is not a function - did you check the console for errors?

This question is similar to: How do you remove all the options of a select box and then add one option and select it with jQuery?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

The above existing answer is mostly for [tag:jquery], but does include a few vanilla answers such as .innerHTML='' as suggested above and also .options.length = 0

It's notable, that you don't seem to send() the created request at all. Also, "the drop down flickers shortly" indicates, that there's a submitted form which refreshes the page.

@Teemu And if they're selecting a button that would be default behaviour...  Hmmm. We need more informatio!

If the button is a submit button, you need event.preventDefault() in the listener.
